# Get static type of struct element

Tags: dictionary, go, declaration, compile-time, type-declaration

I've looked in the Golang documentation and haven't seen an example of how to achieve what I'm looking to do. Specifically, I'm trying to write a map from inodes, represented by `syscall.Stat_t.Ino`, which has type `uint64` on my machine, to ino_entry, defined as

```
type ino_entry struct {
    st    *syscall.Stat_t
    nodes []string
}
```

where nodes represents the names of all the files hard linked to the inode.

However, I want to avoid putting the literal type `uint64` in the specification of the map if I can. That is, instead of writing `map [uint64] ino_entry`, I'd prefer to write `map [typeof(syscall.Stat_t.Ino)] ino_entry`, where `typeof(x)` returns the static (i.e., compile-time) type of `x`. I've tried `map [syscall.Stat_t.Ino] ino_entry` and, by analogy with type switches, `map [syscall.Stat_t.Ino.(type)] ino_entry`, but both of these are syntax errors. Needless to say, `map [reflect.Typeof(syscall.Stat_t.Ino)] ino_entry` doesn't work. As far as I can tell, the only way to implement this without hardcoding the type of the structure element is to use `inomap := make(map [interface{}] ino_entry)` and then access the elements using type assertions (I don't know the correct syntax for this though).

Is there a way to declare the type of a variable based on the static type of another variable, or struct or interface member, without hardcoding that type explicitly?

Comment: It doesn't look like what I asked for is possible, so I submitted an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=4626) to Go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use Reflection to ensure machine portability. If that is the case there is a better tool you can use.

`go build` can handle conditional file inclusion for a build based on arch and os.

So create some files for each arch and os combination you support. At the top of each file add some build constraints.

`// +build linux,386` for instance will cause the go command to only use this file on linux machines with a 386 arch.

Then in that file add a type alias for the type that fits that arch: `type Ino uint64`

Finally create your map as a `map[Ino]ino_entry`.

Wala! machine portability using type aliasing and conditional file inclusion for go.

You can read more about go's build constraints here: http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/

Comment: Accepted since you told me the best workaround for the machine portability issue (although in this case, it doesn't look like it will necessarily be a problem).

Answer (score 0):

Cf. the last question in the OP: Yes, there is a way how to declare a variable's type based on type of any expression, without hardcopying the expression's type:

```
v := expr // equal to var v typeof(expr); v = expr;
```

`expr` also includes most of by you mentioned entities, i.e. another variable, a struct typed "thing", but *not* an interface member (as there are no members of anything ever mentioned in the specs).

Unfortunately, this has nothing to do with declaring a map type, where/when the *type literal* used is in the form `map[T]U`. Here both `T` and `U` *cannot* be *inferred* as in the case of the short variable declaration discussed above.

Answer (score 0):

`Stat_t` has the [same definition](http://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Stat_t) for any machine, and its `Ino` field is always `uint64`, so this shouldn't be a problem here.

If there is a compile-time operator to get this type statically, it must be well-hidden.

However, you could define a type alias: `type ino_id uint64`, which looks more readable to me.